# How to Change the Scene in Unity with Code

Tags: unity-game-engine

Good morning, I'm just trying to change the scene in Unity at the touch of a button. But I don't know how to do that in the code.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

Comment: I don't want to be the toxic stackoverflow guy, but it is actually much faster to google such things first, rather than ask it on stackoverflow immediately. Doing this will save you a lot of negative reactions.

Comment: @blijde_broers this has nothing to do with being toxic ;) There are certain standards on StackOverflow for [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ... this question clearly breaks with both ;) And additionally uses unrelated tags ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SceneManager.LoadScene (name);